# N-number of arrays or Collection?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I move from using n number of arrays to using list with the following example. I'm trying to find out if using a Collection would be better? Or even how can I attempt to do this?

**eg**

```
    params(0, 0) = "guid" 'store procedure variable name
    params(0, 1) = "S" 'data type
    params(0, 2) = strGUID 'value
```

**Update:**

After trying @christiandev suggestion.

How could store this in a variable?

```
Dim sqlparams = New List(Of MySqlParameter)()
Dim param = New MySqlParameter("?iguid", MySqlDbType.String, strGUID)
```

`ds = objMySQL.getDataSetFromStoredProcedure("get_user_credits", "credits", param, DBName)`

```
Error message
- Value of msql type cannot be converted into a System.Array
```

Comment: if params was a class storing that info, a List<Param> could be an easy to use collection of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use List of `SqlParameter`, and keep adding to this instead...

```
Dim sqlParams = New List(Of SqlParameter)()
Dim parameter = New SqlParameter("@guid", SqlDbType.VarChar, strGUID)
sqlParams.Add(parameter)
```

**NOTE**: I used a C# -> VB.Net converter for my C# code.

**EDIT**: Adding multiple

```
Dim sqlParams = New List(Of SqlParameter)() From { _
    New SqlParameter("@guid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "strGuid"), _
    New SqlParameter("@guid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "strGuid"), _
    New SqlParameter("@guid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "strGuid") _
}

MethodWithSqlParams(sqlParams)

Public Shared Sub MethodWithSqlParams(sqlParams As List(Of SqlParameter))
    For Each sqlParameter As var In sqlParams
      'work with sql param
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Based on comments

You could overload the function/method `getDataSetFromStoredProcedure` with...

```
Public Function getDataSetFromStoredProcedure(ByVal SPName As String, 
                                          ByVal DSName As String, 
                                          ByVal sqlParams As List(Of SqlParameter), 
                                     ByVal DBName As String) As System.Data.DataSet
```

Then, you could mostly use the same code, but remove this block...

```
If Not (params Is Nothing) Then
                    For i = 0 To UBound(params) - 1
                        Select Case UCase(params(i, 1))
                            Case "I" 'integer
                                var = New MySqlParameter(CStr(params(i, 0)), MySqlDbType.Int32)
                            Case "B" 'boolean
                                var = New MySqlParameter(CStr(params(i, 0)), MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                            Case "S" 'string
                                var = New MySqlParameter(CStr(params(i, 0)), MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                        End Select
                        var.Value = params(i, 2)
                        comCommand.Parameters.Add(var)
                    Next
                End If
```

and replace it with...

```
comCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray())
```

Comment: Thanks, this can take x number of params correct?. Say i wanted to pass more than 3?

Comment: thanks, i forgot to mention. Please see the update question.

Comment: see the updated question, I have included the code.

Comment: What I want to do at some stage is to refactor into less lines at some stage.

Comment: Do you own the `getDataSetFromStoredProcedure` method/function? can you alter the code in there? or is it widely used?

Comment: The same function is widely used, but when the same principles. Taking a procedure name, param, dbname.

Comment: okay I have resolved the error, just changed the return type in the "StoreProcedure" for params from Array to MySQLParameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63484/discussion-between-harry-and-christiandev).